# C# MySql TransactionScope

Tags: c#, mysql

My system have 2 databases in the sames MySql. Business is make sure data insert into 2 databases in the same transaction completely. Below is my sample:

```
public void test()
{
    int returnValue = 0;
    System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    try
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            returnValue = TestA(returnValue, writer);

            returnValue = TestB(returnValue, writer);

            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

private static int TestB(int returnValue, System.IO.StringWriter writer)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection2 = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=test;user id=root;password=root;port=3307;characterset=utf8;connectiontimeout=72000;"))
    {
        connection2.Open();

        // Execute the second command in the second database.
        returnValue = 0;
        MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand("Insert tbb (`time`)value ('10:00:00')", connection2);
        returnValue = command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command2: {0}", returnValue);
    }
    return returnValue;
}

private static int TestA(int returnValue, System.IO.StringWriter writer)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection1 = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=test1;user id=root;password=root;port=3307;characterset=utf8;connectiontimeout=72000;"))
    {
        connection1.Open();

        // Create the SqlCommand object and execute the first command.
        MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand("Insert tb1 (`Name`, `Value`)value ('ai', '2017-04-26')", connection1);
        returnValue = command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command1: {0}", returnValue);
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

When I run, I got error:

> Multiple simultaneous connections or connections with different
>   connection strings inside the same transaction are not currently
>   supported.

Why does it happen?

if cannot fix, please give me others solutions.

Comment: the error is pretty clear. it is not supported. You could try using only 1 connection and then in the second query do Insert "test1..tb1"

Comment: Please give me others the solutions

Comment: Basically both connections use same server instance at the same time without closing previous connection, which causes concurrency problem. The solution is using different `TransactionScope` for each connection (with `Complete` method after finishing every transaction) & include `AutoEnlist=false`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto if connection is included `AutoEnlist=false`, both transaction are working separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static int TestA(int returnValue, System.IO.StringWriter writer)
{
    .... USE SAME CONNECTION AS TESTA HERE

    // Create the SqlCommand object and execute the first command.
                                                      ****THIS*****
    MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand("Insert `test1`.`tb1` (`Name`, `Value`)value ('ai', '2017-04-26')", connection1);
                                                      ****THIS*****
    returnValue = command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command1: {0}", returnValue);
}

return returnValue;
```

}

so, what i mean is.... dont use 2 connections. use 1 connection and specify the database name toghether with the table

Comment: Cannot. Since 2 tables in separate database.

Comment: you can if it is the same server... well... i think

Comment: Oh men, sorry for my mistake. Your solution work correctly. Thanks.
But I have a question. If 2 databases are separately, how to do it?

Comment: Perhaps you need to separate current single transaction scope for both of them into 2 transaction scopes. Ensure the first connection is complete (to be closed and disposed afterwards) before initiating second one with different DB.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto um, but how to make sure both data insert database completely? according to your point, if the second connection has problem, the first connection cannot be rolled back

Comment: @AiLe My suggestion is using `BeginTransaction()` method for each connection, execute each query command inside try block with `ExecuteNonQuery()` & `Commit()`, if exception thrown use `Rollback()` method to reverse previous state.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Your solution is good. However, my problem is 2 databases are in different server. I tried to use transactionscope but cannot :(

Comment: I also think in you case the only option is to manage manually begintranstaction and commit first if second succeeded. You're not sharing data among those 2 databases at that specific point so there's no reason why that wouldnt work.

Comment: @user5328504 Please teach me to manage manually begintransaction and commit. 2 databases store important transaction of businesses, so I make sure both databases store correct data.

Comment: @AiLe what I mean is: 1. Open transaction in fisrt database 2. Open transaction in second database. 3. Execute first query 4. Execute second query. 5. If bot suceeded, commit both. If any failed, rollback both

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
 MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
        private  int TestB(int returnValue, System.IO.StringWriter writer)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=test;user id=root;password=root;port=3307;characterset=utf8;connectiontimeout=72000;");

                conn.Open();

                // Execute the second command in the second database.
                returnValue = 0;
                MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand("Insert tbb (`time`)value ('10:00:00')", conn);
                returnValue = command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command2: {0}", returnValue);
                conn.Close();
               return returnValue;
        }

        private  int TestA(int returnValue, System.IO.StringWriter writer)
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=test1;user id=root;password=root;port=3307;characterset=utf8;connectiontimeout=72000;");

                conn.Open();

                // Create the SqlCommand object and execute the first command.
                MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand("Insert tb1 (`Name`, `Value`)value ('ai', '2017-04-26')", conn);
                returnValue = command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command1: {0}", returnValue);

                conn.Close();

            return returnValue;
        }
```

Comment: First time I thought simply adding `conn.Close()` on first `using` block will work, but when seeing this post, I think that you need separate `TransactionScope` for both connections.

Comment: this is just a very basic way.. i'm just modifying his code a bit. and he says not working.. i think it's impossible.. if this doesn't work. he clean the connections first to his database itself not in code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create multiple `MySqlConnection` objects within a single `TransactionScope`; if you do, you will get the error you saw. This is tracked as [MySQL Bug 50773](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50773).

You may want to upgrade to https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector (an OSS MySQL connector library that's compatible with MySql.Data) which [does support TransactionScope](https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#transactionscope).